# How make unique constraint for references over one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I am making several tables that will store data about the work of employees.

```
CREATE TABLE job_group (
   job_group_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    job_group  varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO job_group (job_group) VALUES ('first'),('second');

CREATE TABLE job_type (
    job_type_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    job_group_id INT REFERENCES job_group(job_group_id) NOT NULL,
    job_type varchar(100)
);


INSERT INTO job_type (job_type, job_group_id) 
VALUES ('office', 1),('output', 2),('outdoor', 1),('work hard', 1), ('vacation', 2), ('plan', null), ('burn Rome', 1);

CREATE TABLE worker (
    worker_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    worker varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO worker VALUES ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Caligula');

CREATE TABLE job (
    job_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    job_data date,
    worker_id INT REFERENCES worker(worker_id) NOT NULL,
    job_type_id INT REFERENCES job_type(job_type_id) NOT NULL,
    amount INT,
    UNIQUE (worker_id, job_data, job_type)
);
```

How to make a restriction so that it is impossible to insert the type of activity (job_type) from different groups on the same day and same worker, for example, both vacation and office?

```
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-08', 1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-08', 1, 3, 4);
--Its correct - job_group_id = 1


INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-07', 3, 6, null);
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-07', 3, 4, 8); --Its correct - job_group_id is null
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-07', 3, 7, 1); --Its correct - job_group_id = 1

INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-09', 2, 1, 8);
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-09', 2, 5, null); --ERROR - job_group_id = 2
```

Comment: I'm lost because you have. annotations "Its correct - job_group_id = 1" but none of the columns are `job_group_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made a mistake) thank you
`
INSERT INTO job (job_data, worker_id, job_type_id, amount)
VALUES ('2020-11-08', 1, 3, 4);
--Its correct - job_group_id = 1
`

Comment: Did you mean `over` and not `ower` in your querstion title?

Comment: @yvw Yes of course!